# kubernetes api access forbidden

Tags: api, ssl, kubernetes, certificate, tls1.2

I'm trying to get cluster info like pods through `curl -k https://172.26.2.101:6443/api/v1/pods` but i'm getting bellow forbidden error, however, I checked the admin rights and made sure it's in the "system:masters" group.

```
{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {
    
  },
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "pods is forbidden: User \"system:anonymous\" cannot list resource \"pods\" in API group \"\" at the cluster scope",
  "reason": "Forbidden",
  "details": {
    "kind": "pods"
  },
  "code": 403
```

Any idea ?!

Answer (score 1):

Solved by capturing certs from the .kube/config file

client-key-data:

```
echo -n "LS0...Cg==" | base64 -d > admin.key
```

client-certificate-data:

```
echo -n "LS0...C==" | base64 -d > admin.crt
```

certificate-authority-data:

```
echo -n "LS0...g==" | base64 -d > ca.crt
```

Then, use

```
curl https://172.26.2.101:6443 \
--key admin.key \
--cert admin.crt 
--cacert ca.crt
```