# kubernetes authentication issue on httpd pod

Tags: kubernetes

keep getting this when trying to go to the web of a httpd pod, what permissions am i missing.

```
{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {
    
  },
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "pods \"pod-httpd\" is forbidden: User \"system:anonymous\" cannot get resource \"pods\" in API group \"\" in the namespace \"default\"",
  "reason": "Forbidden",
  "details": {
    "name": "pod-httpd",
    "kind": "pods"
  },
  "code": 403
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [kubernetes api access forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66292362/kubernetes-api-access-forbidden)

Comment: @PeterBadida that's a different issue. the other request goes to the api server. this one goes to a random pod.

Comment: how did you deploy your pod? and how, and where are you making that request?

Comment: @suren Same solution though :)

Comment: @PeterBadida well, he is sending the request wrong. he is sending it against the IP address of the master, instead of the pod directly. But he doesn't need to solve this issue. just send the request right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is clear `User "system:anonymous"` means k8s recognising you as `anonymous` user and that is why it is giving forbidden reason for accessing the desired resources.
So, when you do `curl https://<ip>:<port>/<endpoint>` you are using TLS for the communication. In this type of communication you need to provide your CA (certificate authority, who signed your certificate) certificate,  and your certificate and key to the curl like below, because in TLS server-client need to be verified.

```
curl https://<ip>:<port>/<endpoint> --key <your_key> --cert <your_cert>  --cacert <ca_cert>
```

N.B: here `you` means the client